# How to test if exception is raised when calling socket.send

Tags: python, unit-testing, exception

This is my first time testing a socket interface using mocking. I have a class which invoked the `_socket.sendto()` method. I would like to test if an exception is raised.

```
class socketUDP(object):

    def __init__(self, host="127.0.0.1", port=2003):
        self.host = host
        self.port = port

        self._socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)


    def send(self, metric, value):

        message = "%s %f\n" % (metric, value)

        try:
            self._socket.sendto(
                message, (self.host, self.port))
        except Exception, e:
            # I would like to test if this exception is raised
            print "Could not relay data: %s" % e
```

Update:
I am writing some unit tests for the send method and one of the tests I want to do is to see if an exception was raised

Comment: "Test" as in you're writing tests for the `send` method, or "test" as in you're trying to figure out, within `send`, whether the exception was thrown? And why are you catching the error inside the method anyway?

Comment: I am writing some unit tests for the send method and one of the tests I want to do is to see if an exception was raised.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `send()` method catches the exception, this will be rather difficult.  You might try [monkey-patching the `socket.send()` method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#patch), but that's an iffy solution at best.  It seems to me that in this case, you're testing implementation details rather than conformance to an interface, which is a questionable strategy to begin with.

If the `send()` method does not catch the exception, you can just use [`assertRaises()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.assertRaises).